# Generate a random string not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to generate a string of random characters just like this example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349404/generate-a-string-of-5-random-characters-in-javascript)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#randomize').click(function() {

    var text = "";
    var possible = "michaeljordanisthebestbasketballplayerofalltime";


    for( var i=0; i < 5; i++ )
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

    return text;

    console.log(text)
    $('.shuffle_text').html(text);

  });

});
```

for some reason it is not working on click - the console.log for text is still empty when I run it. Any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=QVf3hGm8la

Comment: hint: what does `return` do?

Comment: Hint 2: try stepping through your function; it should reveal why there's nothing logged.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#randomize').click(function() {

    var text = "";
    var possible = "michaeljordanisthebestbasketballplayerofalltime";


    for( var i=0; i < 5; i++ )
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

    console.log(text)
    $('.shuffle_text').html(text);

  });

});
```

Removed return.

@jsfiddle, you don't need to return anything because jQuery won't do anything with it.

Also, replace your possible string to something like "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789". This will increase the randomness since you have much the same characters in the current string.